# how to save a file in STL format

Tags: export, save, 3d-printing

***good morning. I have written a code of a spherical gyroid when I run it, it gives me a 3D drawing. now I need to save it in STL format for 3D printing. Mathematical doesn't have the option to save the file in STL format. I have been asking this question but I've gotten a concrete detailed answer. If someone can write me the full code on how to go about it I will be very grateful***

```
r = 2 Pi;
model = ContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, {x, -r, 
   r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},
  RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2),
  Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: `Export["model.stl",model]` works just fine for me.  The STL file, however, is defect-ridden, which cannot be fixed with `RepairMesh`.  This will be a very difficult model to print as there is no guidance on wall thickness or what is an inner vs. outer surface.

Answer (score 4):

```
Export["a.stl", DiscretizeGraphics[model]]
```