# How to save in STL format for 3D printing?

Tags: export, code-review, code-request, 3d-printing, stl-format

I have the code of a spherical gyroid written in Mathematica and I am unable to save it in STL format. The image is shown in the figure below and the code is shown below. I need help with a code on how to save it as an STL file.

[image]

```
r = 2 Pi;
model = ContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, {x, -r, 
   r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},
  RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2),
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", 
  Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .3}]
```

Comment: `Export["output.stl", model]` doesn't work?

Comment: Good evening sir, the code doesn't work, I will be grateful if you give me your own code. I have been stressing about this for two weeks now

Answer (score 2):

First remove the `Box` and `Axes`

```
r=2 Pi;
model = ContourPlot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, {x, -r,r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2),Mesh -> None,PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface",Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .3}
, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Now you might use the answer (thanks @Henrik Schumacher)  of your own question from march2020  [how to save a file in STL format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216309/how-to-save-a-file-in-stl-format)

```
Export[…,DiscretizeGraphics[model]]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer Sir, but here is the complete code, once I run it gives me an error...r = 2 Pi; model = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, {x, -r, 
   r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}, 
  RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2), 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", 
  Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .3}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
  Export["a.stl", DiscretizeGraphics[model]]]

Comment: The code runs on v12 Windows 10. What errors occur?

Comment: I will be grateful if you send me your own code Sir, I have that windows version

Comment: Copy the three lines of code from my answer, quit your kernel and run the code. That's all. That's all I have.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I have seen it now. I am grateful

Comment: In my computer( Linux, i5-1065G4,16G memory), the `model` can't  `DiscretizeGraphics`, it cause the kernel crash.

Comment: @cvgmt Amazing, what is your Mathematica version?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  12.1.1 in Linux

Comment: In 12.1.1,we must set `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None` to remove the extra sphere, it maybe a bug. Perhaps this settings cause the kernel crash when we using `DiscretizeGraphics`

Answer (score 2):

Another way maybe use `RegionPlot3D`.  Here we calculate the normal of surface and then perturbate the surface along the normal to create a thick surface.

```
r = 2 Pi;
f = Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x];
normal = Grad[f, {x, y, z}];
norm = normal^2 // Total // Evaluate;
model = RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2 && f^2 <= 0.01 norm, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, 
   r}, {z, -r, r}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
Export["output.stl", model]
Import["output.stl"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried a number of suggestions from different posts to make surface thickness work for 3D printing, but nothing worked for me until I used "Export[…,DiscretizeGraphics[model]]" as shown on this thread, and then it worked like a charm.