# Prepare Lorentz attractor for 3D Printing

Tags: differential-equations, 3d-printing

How can I export Lorentz attractor from MMA as obj or stl format to Print3D.

```
solution = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
Derivative[1][y][t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], 
Derivative[1][z][t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t], x[0] == z[0] == 0, 
y[0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 400}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];

g=ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s],{t, 0, 50}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: see [Export as 3D file type STL for 3D printing](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/176000) and [how-to-save-in-stl-format-for-3d-printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235291/how-to-save-in-stl-format-for-3d-printing)  and [STL](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/STL.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
Export["test.stl", g /. Line -> Tube]
```

```
Export["test.stl",g /. Line[a_] -> Tube[a, .5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tube` as styling directive:

```
pplot = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 50}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Specularity[White, 10], Tube[.25]}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 1000, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Export["lorenz.stl", pplot]
```

[image]

```
Export["lorenz.obj", pplot]
```

[image]